# Return json from php to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get back a json object from php to then use in my ajax.

My ajax is

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var eventsListPath = "/php/eventsList.php";

  $.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: eventsListPath,
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
  var json = JSON.parse(data);
  $('#eventInformation').html(json[table]);
  }
 });
});
```

and then my php does stuff but I basically want to return a string (plus more, but getting the string to work first would probably help the rest):

```
$obj->table="hey";

echo json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

But the line

```
$('#eventInformation').html(json[table]);
```

seems to only give me back an error:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please check my answer below. If it solves the problem you can tick the check image at the side of the answer :)

Comment: Check your JSON response from `echo json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` by pasting this response at http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: $obj->table="hey"; echo json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. This is pretty much what we know already though..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **.** operator, also there is no need to parse the JSON string it is already in JSON form :)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var eventsListPath = "/php/eventsList.php";

     $.ajax({
         type: 'get',
         url: eventsListPath,
         data: {},
         success: function (data) {
             $('#eventInformation').html(data.table);
         }
     });
 });
```

ON PHP, ensure that you are instantiating the response data like below

```
$obj = new StdClass;
$obj->table="hey";
```

Comment: @StevenJacks please press ctrl + f5 to refresh the browser cache.

Comment: Still: 
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: How about using `$.parseJSON` instead of `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @StevenJacks, the response is already in JSON form. we don't need to parse it to JSON form anymore. Check my updated answer

Comment: Okay that gets rid of the error, but now the code isn't showing up in the div #eventInformation. alert(data.table) comes back as 'undefined'.

Comment: @StevenJacks, can you please check if the casing on your code are identical?

Comment: Not for another 90 minutes, sadly.

Comment: @StevenJacks Show JSON response on your question. You can do that by using sniffing tools like fiddler

Comment: Lol what? o.o I don't know what that means.

Comment: @StevenJacks, obviously you do not understand. SORRY for that. Though you can google what is a HTTP sniffing tool

Comment: @StevenJacks try chrome developer tools , Click the filename and click response option in the network tab. it will show you the reponse.

Comment: @StevenJacks, we cannot help you if you would not provide the JSON data :) good luck with your problem

Comment: What JSON data do you need? 

$obj = new StdClass;
 $obj->table="hey"; 

 echo json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

This is everything that goes in it..

Comment: We need the output of that statement. Not the code itself, we can see it from your question :)

Answer (score 0):

first, use the Network Monitor to see the result of the HTTP request
e.g. in Firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-GB/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

then, try this code who let jQuery do the JSON parsing in the AJAX call :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var eventsListPath = "/php/eventsList.php";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: eventsListPath,
        data: {},
        result: "json"
        success: function (dataJson) {
            $('#eventInformation').html(json.table);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check the response is properly parsed as json. if any data is present before the json array, javascript will throw exceptions. Use the chrome's developer tools response tab in the network option for seeing the response. If it's ok , try the below code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var eventsListPath = "/php/eventsList.php";

     $.ajax({
         method: "get",
         url: eventsListPath,
         dataType : "json",
         data: {}, //data 
         success: function (data) {
             $('#eventInformation').html(data.table); 
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: The code is returning JSON as seen on his PHP code :)

Comment: He is not returning an array. He is returning an PHP object